# Custom UITableViewCell not working (drawRect:) on device [Swift]

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, drawrect

I made a simple project where I subclass a `UITableViewCell` to the test `drawrect:` method. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I set the background of every other cell `backgroundColor`. It works on simulator but not on device.
I know that there are easier methods to get alternating cell backgrounds, but this is just an easy example to show that drawRect doesn't seem to work on my device in this case.

Here is my code:

```
// The subclassed custom cell

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
       var fColor: UIColor?

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        fColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }
    
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        fColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }
 /*   
    func setFcolor(c:UIColor){
        fColor = c
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
  */

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        var context: CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        var color: UIColor = fColor!
        color.set()
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect)
        
    }
}


// My cell creation


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell") as CustomCell
            
    cell.fColor = indexPath.row % 2 == 0 ? UIColor.whiteColor() : UIColor.blackColor()
    cell.textLabel.text="row#\(indexPath.row)"
   
    return cell
}
```

Here is the setup in the storyboard:

[image: customcell]

[image: customcell2]

And here is the expected outcome on the simulator:

[image: simulator]

But on my device (iOS7.1) every cell background is white

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the backgroundColor property of UITableViewCell :

```
if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {

  cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
else {

  cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the answer I'm looking for. Like I said there are easier ways to achieve alternating cell colors. This was just an example to use `drawRect:` which isn't showing up on the device, but on the simulator it is.